# What is the best way to authenticate a Gitlab CI/CD Runner to Hashicorp Vault?

Tags: gitlab, runner

I want to bring this discussion over here. What's the best approach/way to authenticate a Gitlab Runner against Hashicorp Vault to pull secrets required to do a deployment in the pipeline?.

### What I've thought already

Generate a TLS certificate from the Docker image that the runner is using. I'm using a image that I've built myself so I can add a certificate to it and then use the TLS auth method https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/cert

But is this a correct way of doing it? I think is solid because with this way we don't have to store a first secret in the CI/CD variables. But wanted to see if someone has a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with k8s, GitLab just released a HashiCorp Vault app you can install in k8s: https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/03/22/gitlab-12-9-released/

Comment: Ok. See the issue linked from the release announcement, maybe some useful data there.

Comment: I took a look at https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth and there are quite a few options there.  You'll have to put the secret _somewhere_, either into GitLab CI as a masked variable (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#masked-variables) or burn it into Docker image. Six of one, half dozen of another, hey?